# How can I share link (image url) on facebook?

Tags: android, facebook, android-facebook, facebook-permissions

I ve searched a lot and finally I decided to ask here.

I cant update my facebook api now.(please do not advice it)

I cant use android stduio for now.(please do not advice it)

I can t share link (image url) on facebook although there are permission which facebook need them to publish.

I use `eclipse mars.`

I have `facebook api 3.7`

I give this perms : `{  "public_profile"  ,"publish_actions"};`

when I write this codes:

```
 Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
 parameters.putString("link","www.imagerul.com/url.jpg" );
 parameters.putString("message", "test message" );  
 response = mFacebook.request("me/feed", parameters,"POST");
```

When I login to facebook with my developer facebook account , facebook ask me to post and it post my sharing successfully.

But when I log in with another facebook account which is not a developer account. Facebook just ask public information not **post** so it is not possible to post. And it gives this error:  `OAuthException (#200) The user hasn't authorized`

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to get your app reviewed before you can use the publish_actions permission with non-developer accounts.

See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review